# Add text to faces of polyhedron

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Is it possible to automate the addition of any text to the faces of a polyhedron, like this manually-drawn graphic shows (the example's odd numbering scheme isn't relevant):

[image: labelled faces of dodecahedron]

It was easy enough to label the vertices:

```
c = 1;
Show[{Graphics3D[
   Text[c++, #] & /@ PolyhedronData["Dodecahedron", "VertexCoordinates"]], 
   PolyhedronData["Dodecahedron"]},
   Boxed -> False]
```

[image: labelled edges of dodecahedron]

(even though some of the text is placed in front of the shape for vertices that are hidden. That's probably soluble.)

But when I tried to do the same thing for faces, nothing worked. `PolyhedronData["Dodecahedron", "Faces"]` returns a GraphicsComplex, rather than coordinates.

Am I overlooking an easy solution/option?

Edit: thanks for these answers, they're all brilliant. If I could combine the text placing of szabolcs' answer with the text quality of belisarius', the perfect solution is in sight!

Comment: Please see my edit.  Now labels should be oriented to point roughly "up", and also align with edges.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here's a funky approach:

```
(* this function just transforms the polygon onto the [0,1] 2D square *)
vtc[face_, up_:{0,0,1}] := Module[{pts, pts2, centre, r, r2, topmost},
  pts = N@face;
  centre = Mean[pts];
  pts = (# - centre & /@ pts);
  r = SingularValueDecomposition[pts][[3]];

  (* these two lines ensure that the text on the outer face 
     of a convex polyhedron is not mirrored *)
  If[Det[r] < 0, r = -r];
  If[Last[centre.r] < 0, r = r.RotationMatrix[\[Pi], {1, 0, 0}]];

  pts2 = Most /@ (pts.r);
  topmost = Part[pts2, First@Ordering[up.# &  /@ pts, -1]];
  r2 = Transpose[{{#2, -#1} & @@ topmost, topmost}];
  r2 /= Norm[r2];
  Rescale[pts2.r2]
]

faces = First /@ First@Normal@PolyhedronData["Dodecahedron", "Faces"];

numbers = 
  Graphics[Text[
      Style[#, Underlined, FontFamily -> "Georgia", 
       FontSize -> Scaled[.3]]]] & /@ Range@Length[faces];

Graphics3D[
 MapThread[{Texture[#1], 
    Polygon[#2, VertexTextureCoordinates -> vtc[#2]]} &, {numbers, 
   faces}],
 Boxed -> False
 ]
```

[image]

Demoing a `"SmallRhombicosidodecahedron"`:

[image]

Comment: As of 11.1, you'd need to add a third argument `"GraphicsComplex"` to the `PolyhedronData[..., "Faces"]` call.

Answer (score 14):

```
a = PolyhedronData["Dodecahedron", "Faces"] /.    GraphicsComplex -> List;
c = 1;
Show[{Graphics3D[
   Text[c++, #] & /@ (Mean /@ (a[[1, #]] & /@ a[[2, 1]]))], 
    PolyhedronData["Dodecahedron"]}, Boxed -> False]
```

**Edit**

Perhaps better:

```
Show[{Graphics3D[
         MapIndexed[Text[#2, #1] &, 
             Mean /@ (PolyhedronData["Dodecahedron", "VertexCoordinates"][[#]] & /@ 
                      PolyhedronData["Dodecahedron", "FaceIndices"])]], 
         PolyhedronData["Dodecahedron"]}, Boxed -> False]
```

**Edit**

Or

```
text = Style[#, 128] & /@ Range[12]
Graphics3D@
 Riffle[Texture /@ text, 
       (Append[#1, {VertexTextureCoordinates -> 
          With[{n = Length[First[#1]]}, Table[1/2 {Cos[2 Pi i/n], Sin[2 Pi i/n]}+ 
                                           {1/2, 1/2}, {i, 0, n - 1}]]}] &) /@ 
   Flatten[Normal[PolyhedronData["Dodecahedron", "Faces"]]]]
```

[image]

Comment: +1, but why not use a single Map operation instead of three?  And toss in a little infix spice while you're at it. ;-)  `Graphics3D[c++ ~Text~ Mean@a[[1, #]] & /@ a[[2, 1]]]`

Comment: Regarding your second edit: I consider the challenge to be doing this for an arbitrary polyhedron.

Comment: Great answer, thanks. It will take me much longer for me to study it. I still haven't heard of half of these functions, let alone learnt how to use them!

Comment: @cormullion Don't hesitate in asking for help here!

Comment: You got my +1 too :-) Do you know how to clip away 3D `Text` that's being obscured by some polygons?  (Such as 10, 15 20 in the question's example graphic)

Comment: @Sza You could use small rectangles with a transparent texture attached to each vertex

Comment: @belisarius thanks so much - you're all really helpful! Here's one question, then: why does your font size value work the way it does in your third edit?

Comment: @cor That is the way `VertexTextureCoordinates` works. Or perhaps I don't understand your question. Anyway, comments is not the right place to ask questions, as nobody but me gets notified and you could get better answers than mine by posting a real question.

Comment: As of 11.1, you'd need to add a third argument `"GraphicsComplex"` to the `PolyhedronData[..., "Faces"]` call.