# Orthogonalize[ ] working as expected only when applied twice

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Applying `Orthogonalize[]` once:

```
v1 = PolyhedronData["Dodecahedron", "VertexCoordinates"][[1]]; 
Graphics3D[Line[{{0, 0, 0}, #}] & /@
  Orthogonalize[{a, b, c} /.
    FindInstance[{a, b, c}.v1 == 0 && (Chop@a != 0.||Chop@b != 0.||Chop@c != 0.),
     {a, b, c}, Reals, 4]], Boxed -> False]
```

[image]

And now twice:

```
Graphics3D[Line[{{0, 0, 0}, #}] & /@
  Orthogonalize@Orthogonalize[{a, b, c} /.
    FindInstance[{a, b, c}.v1 == 0 && (Chop@a != 0.||Chop@b != 0.||Chop@c != 0.),
     {a, b, c}, Reals, 4]], Boxed -> False]
```

[image]

Errr ... Why?

Comment: So, [Szabolcs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8154079/add-text-to-faces-of-polyhedron/8155008#comment10011483_8155008) gets a congrats, but I don't?!?  :D

Comment: Hmmm, ran a recalc, and it didn't work out like I expected. Below 5k, again.

Comment: @rcollyer Congrats!! :D  I was out dining ;-)

Comment: @Szabolcs, thanks. Honestly, I was just poking fun at him.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I also assumed it would be a numerical error, but didn't quite understand *why*, so I tried to implement [Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram_schmidt#The_Gram.E2.80.93Schmidt_process) myself, hoping to understand the problem on the way:

```
(* projects onto a unit vector *)
proj[u_][v_] := (u.v) u

Clear[gm, gramSchmidt]

gm[finished_, {next_, rest___}] := 
 With[{v = next - Plus @@ Through[(proj /@ finished)[next]]}, 
  gm[Append[finished, Normalize@Chop[v]], {rest}]
 ]

gm[finished_, {}] := finished

gramSchmidt[vectors_] := gm[{}, vectors]
```

<sup>(Included for illustration only, I simply couldn't quite figure out what's going on before I reimplemented it myself.)</sup>

A critical step here, which I didn't realize before, is **deciding whether a vector we get is zero or not *before* the normalization step** (see `Chop` in my code).  Otherwise we might get something tiny, possibly a mere numerical error, which is then normalized back into a large value.

This seems to be controlled by the `Tolerance` option of `Orthogonalize`, and indeed, raising the tolerance, and forcing it to discard tiny vectors fixes the problem you describe.  `Orthogonalize[ ... , Tolerance -> 1*^-10]` works in a single step.

Comment: I think you're right. Using your code with and without `Chop` in `FindInstance` gives me two planes whose normals differ by a sign. I get the same thing using `Orthogonalize` with `Tolerance -> 10^-10`.

Answer (score 6):

I think the first result is due to numerical error, taking

```
sys = {a,b,c}/.FindInstance[
          {a, b, c}.v1 == 0 && (Chop@a != 0. || Chop@b != 0. || Chop@c !=0.), 
          {a, b, c}, Reals, 4];
```

then `MatrixRank@sys` returns 2, therefor the system itself is only two dimensional.  To me, this implies that the first instance of `Orthogonalize` is generating a numerical error, and the second instance is using the out of plane error to give you your three vectors. Removing the `Chop` conditions fixes this,

```
Orthogonalize[{a, b, c} /.
    N@FindInstance[{a, b, c}.v1 == 0,{a, b, c}, Reals, 4]]
```

where `N` is necessary to get rid of the `Root` terms that appear.  This gives you a two-dimensional system, but you can get a third by taking the cross product.

**Edit**: Here's further evidence that its numerical error due to `Chop`.

With `Chop`, `FindInstance` gives me

```
{{64., 3.6, 335.108}, {-67., -4.3, -350.817}, {0, 176., 0}, 
 {-2., -4.3, -10.4721}}
```

Without `Chop`, I get

```
{{-16.8, 3.9, -87.9659}, {6.6, -1.7, 34.558}, {13.4, -4.3, 70.1633}, 
 {19.9, -4.3, 104.198}}
```

which is a significant difference between the two.

Comment: This can also be cured by applying `Normalize /@` before orthogonalization

Comment: @Szabolcs, at least on my system, it doesn't, and I wouldn't expect it to as the numerical errors remain.

Comment: I'm on 32-bit Windows, 8.0.4, `Orthogonalize[Normalize /@ (...)]` fixes it here.  The vectors I get from FindInstance are the same as on your machine.

Comment: @Szabolcs, I think I see what the misunderstanding was. Yes, using `Normalize` first eliminates the need for the second `Orthogonalize` on my machine (v.7.0.1 on MacOS), also. But, it still returns 3 non-zero vectors, which is the error I was referring to. There should be only 2 non-zero vectors, but `Chop` introduces enough numerical error to give an erroneous out-of-plane term which `Orthogonalize` picks up on.

Comment: It returns two zero-vectors here if I use Normalize first.  I believe the key is deciding which vector is zero and which isn't during the Gram-Schmidt process (see my answer, and the Tolerance option to Orthogonalize)

Comment: Also, I think using `Chop` *inside* `FindInstance` (not on the result returned by it) is not wrong per se, it must still be true that all vectors returned by `FindInsntace` are in the same plane.

Comment: @Szabolcs, you're right in that using `Chop` isn't wrong, per se, but care must be taken. Using `Chop`, and `N` for that matter, forces mma to use floating point arithmetic which means we need to pay closer attention to what exactly we're doing. I can't tell you how often I've been bitten by this; twice in the same homework assignment!

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it is a characteristic of the default GramSchmidt method?

Try:  `Method -> "Reorthogonalization"` or `Method -> "Householder"`.

Comment: The default is actually "ModifiedGramSchmidt".  Just an observation after playing with it.

Comment: I think it is strictly a numerical error due to his use of `Chop`, as without it, you get only 2 non-zero vectors.